# Tracking time spent at a location in Android

Tags: java, android, location, geofencing

Maybe I haven't been googling the right thing, but I am trying to figure out how to track the time a user spends at a particular location. I did some [research](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html), and I found that I could use the Geofencing API to define a Geofence location and then fire off an IntentService when the user's current location is within the Geofence. How do I begin to track the time spent at this location? Any insights/comments/tutorials/sample code would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much idea here, but I think there is a LocationListener that listens for updates on change in device's location.

You can compute time between consequent location updates to find the time spent at the most recent location.

For details, you can go through LocationListener/LocationManager documentation on developer.android.com.

Comment: How do you propose computing the time? I was thinking of firing off a timer when the user enters the Geofence

Comment: Or, you could record the timestamp each time user enters a new geofence and subtract consecutive timestamps to get time spent within one geofence, that will include less processing then to have a timer running continuosly!